# Jenkins: aborting the execution of jobs in a multijob

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Jenkins. There is a multijob that calls some jobs. I can stop the execution of this multijob (both manually and by timeout, using **Build-timeout** plugin). Nevertheless, the jobs running by the current multijob, don’t cease its execution even in case of interruption of the multijob.
Is there a way to make it so, that upon the forced shutdown of multijob, those jobs that were initiated would also cease working?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a option in multi job upstream job configuration to "Abort all other jobs"

[image]

have configured two child jobs.
I have aborted parent job and it in turn aborted 2 child jobs

[image]

Try the same and feel free to revert in case you need additional information

Your multi job can have many multi phase's , we can make the multi project run other multi phase only when its previous multi phase is successful.

[image]

Bu enabling this if any child jobs fail in above phases the main job will automatically fail.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing not just for the multijob phase, but for the entire project, i.e. multijob project?

Comment: I meant a slightly different thing. Suppose, I have a project ('Proj') with multi phases ('A', 'B'). Multi phase 'A' contains job 'a', and multi phase 'B' - job 'b'. If, for example, the multi phase 'A' is executed, (and correspondingly, the job ‘a’), and I cancel the execution of the ‘Proj’ project, then multi phase 'A' stops, but job 'a' – not. I need the ‘a’ to stop too, that’s what I am aiming at.

Comment: @Nightwalker Stoping parent Multi phase 'A' would actually stop its child job 'a',  i did the same thing as part of testing (please refer attached screenshot), can you please try same configuration and do let me know if it is not working.

Comment: I tried making a minimal test project and seems that I found the issue. If we set in the MultiJob Phase the value of the property "Job execution type" as "Running phase jobs in parallel", then when cancelling the MultiJob Phase, the dependent jobs also stop. But of we set "Running phase jobs sequentially", then upon  cancelling MultiJob Phase, the dependent jobs continue the execution. 


Are there any suggestions of why it may happen?

Comment: yes,when running multi jobs in a sequential way we can stop the execution of next multi job phase by enabling condition,please refer to last screen shot of above answer.

Comment: @prudviraj - Can we have an example of it

Comment: @AJm can you please let me know what example you need ? which is missing in the answer